# Possible to edit Firebase Cloud Functions on an iPad and deploy changes?

Tags: ios, ipad, google-cloud-functions

Since the iPad does not have a terminal, file system, and/or a PC level IDE, is it possible to actually work on Firebase Cloud Functions? I would love to bring my iPad with me on vacation instead of my MacBook, but I need a more reliable way to work on my projects. I have read that people tried cloud based solutions or other SSH hacks but I have no idea where to start. Anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new function in the [Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), you have several options for providing the source, including an inline source editor.  These is not available in the Firebase console.

[image]